# bootstrap doesn't work with jsp

Tags: java, css, jsp

I am try connect min lib css bootstrap for my jsp page.
But nothing happened!
My proposal.jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Tests List</h3>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
</button>
<c:if test="${!empty listTests}">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="25">Test ID</th>
                <th width="80">Test Name</th>
                <th width="80">Test Author</th>
                <th width="120">Test Description</th>
                <th width="60">Test IsFree</th>
                <th width="120">Test Comment to Admin</th>
                <th width="120">Test Section</th>
                <th width="120">Test Status</th>
                <th width="60">Review</th>
                <th width="60">Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <c:forEach items="${listTests}" var="test">
            <tr>
                <td>${test.id}</td>
                <td>${test.name}</td>
                <td>${test.author}</td>
                <td>${test.description}</td>
                <td>${test.isFree}</td>
                <td>${test.commentToAdmin}</td>
                <td>${test.section}</td>
                <td>${test.status}</td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/tests/review/${test.id}' />">Review</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/tests/remove/${test.id}' />">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

My folders hierarchy:

[folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rzpv.jpg)

How you can see - in code I connected css and js file. But there is result which I have(yep , info I loading with DB) :
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dADw2.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an absolute reference to the files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yep wherever those guys are sitting. Absolute is the way to go.

Comment: Nope. This didn't help

Comment: In your browser, try to access /css/bootstrap.min.css.  Do you see that file?

Comment: http://localhost:8085/css/bootstrap.min.css - Nope
http://localhost:8085/Diplom/css/bootstrap.min.css - Nope
=(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pointing from relative path of your JSP, please use absolute paths from the root of your project i.e. from `webapp`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JSP you should add context path to make it work:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

`<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`